# Need help for machine learning trading code in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'd like to test a daytrading logic using machine learning algorithms.

I wrote a simple code, but not working, so I need your help.

Here it goes:

**Logic**

- Concept : Buy S&P 500 index at day Open, exit at day Close.
- Independent variable : `dayOpen/dayOpen(1)`, `dayOpen/dayClose(1)`, `dayOpen/dayHigh(1)`, `dayOpen/dayLow(1)` ....... `dayOpen/dayLow(2)`

  ----> `dayOpen(1)` = Opening price of previous day
- Dependent variable : `if Close > Open` assign 1, otherwise 0
- Trading logic : Using `kNN` or `SVM` algorithm with 8 features, predict todays index direction. If up, buy index, otherwise hold cash.
- I tried to train test data with recent 60 rolling data.

My codes are shown below, but I got error message. Anybody can help me?

Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from sklearn import neighbors, svm

def price(stock, start):
    price = web.DataReader(name=stock, data_source='yahoo', start=start)
    return price

clf1 = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
clf2 = svm.SVC()   

data = price('^KS11','2000-01-01')

data['Open(1)'] = data.Open/data.Open.shift(1)
data['High(1)'] = data.Open/data.High.shift(1)
data['Low(1)'] = data.Open/data.Low.shift(1)
data['Close(1)'] = data.Open/data.Close.shift(1)
data['Open(2)'] = data.Open/data.Open.shift(2)
data['High(2)'] = data.Open/data.High.shift(2)
data['Low(1)'] = data.Open/data.Low.shift(2)
data['Close(2)'] = data.Open/data.Close.shift(2)
data['Result'] = np.where(data.Close/data.Open>1,1,0)
data['Close/Open'] = data.Close/data.Open
data['Prediction'] = pd.Series()

for i in range(61, len(data.index)):
    x = data.iloc[i-61:i,6:14]
    y = data.Result[i-61:i]
    clf2.fit(x,y)
    data.Prediction[i] = clf2.predict(x)[-1]

data = data.dropna()
data['Profit'] = np.where(data.Result == 1,data['Close/Open'],1).cumprod()
print(data.iloc[:,6:])
data.Profit.plot()
plt.show()
```

> ```
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-8-8c10864c79e2> in <module>()
>      29     x = data.iloc[i-61:i,6:14]
>      30     y = data.Result[i-61:i]
> ---> 31     clf2.fit(x,y)
>      32     data.Prediction[i] = clf2.predict(x)[-1]
>      33 
>
> C:\Users\yiugn_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
>     148         self._sparse = sparse and not callable(self.kernel)
>     149 
> --> 150         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr', dtype=np.float64, order='C')
>     151         y = self._validate_targets(y)
>     152 
>
> C:\Users\yiugn_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py
> in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy,
> force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples,
> ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)`enter code here`
>     396                              % (array.ndim, estimator_name))
>     397         if force_all_finite:
> --> 398             _assert_all_finite(array)
>     399 
>     400     shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)
>
> C:\Users\yiugn_\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py
> in _assert_all_finite(X)
>      52             and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
>      53         raise ValueError("Input contains NaN, infinity"
> ---> 54                          " or a value too large for %r." % X.dtype)
>      55 
>      56 
>
> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').
> ```

Comment: When you perform shift operation, it results in *Nans* getting created as it shifts all elements downwards by 1 level. You must [***impute***](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Imputer.html) the missing values for these and then run the `fit` method on it.

Comment: @Mickil Maveli Thanks, I solved